# AppVeyor - Ubuntu not recognised as an image

Tags: linux, ubuntu, integration, continuous, appveyor

I managed to get AppVeyor to build my project and deploy it for Windows but now I would like to have it build for Linux too. When I add Ubuntu to the image section, I get an error that it hasn't been recognised and the build fails. In the settings on the website Ubuntu is not an option, the only options are versions of Visual Studio. Am I missing something? I tested my appveyor.yml file in the online validate tool and it confirmed that it was correct.

This is the yml file I am using:

```
version: 1.0.{build}
image: 
    - Visual Studio 2017
    - Ubuntu

configuration:
- Release

cache:
- build/lib -> appveyor.yml

before_build:
- cmd: >-
    git submodule update --init --recursive

    if not exist build\ mkdir build

    cd build

    cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ../

- sh: git submodule update --init --recursive
- sh: mkdir build
- sh: cd build
- sh: cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"

build:
    project: "build/Games_Engineering.sln"
    parallel: true
    verbosity: minimal

after_build:
- cmd: >-
    7z a game.zip %APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER%/build/bin/%CONFIGURATION%/Coursework.exe %APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER%/build/bin/%CONFIGURATION%/*.dll %APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER%/build/bin/%CONFIGURATION%/res 

artifacts:
  - path: build/*.zip
    name: Game_zip

deploy:
    description: 'Game package'
    provider: GitHub
    on:
        appveyor_repo_tag: true
        CONFIGURATION: Release
    auth_token:
        secure: gaNPfzFDf02yceIPsb+6lUEf/YfexgCZr7tOGgLybABn/2LdEaMLymgfZLgdUivC
    artifact: Game_zip            
    prerelease: true
```

The error I get is: Failed to setup build job 'Image: Ubuntu': Build worker image not found: Ubuntu

Comment: Can you provide some more details such as the yml file or the output from the build errors you are seeing.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more details on providing a MCVE.

Comment: *"I tested my appveyor.yml file in the online validate tool and it confirmed that it was correct."* - Don't trust that tool...

Comment: I edited the first post to include more information.

Answer (score 3):

AppVeyor for Linux is currently at private beta. Please drop a email to `team at appveyor dot com` (do not forget to mention your AppVeyor account), and we will enable it for you.

More details are [here](https://www.appveyor.com/blog/2018/03/06/appveyor-for-linux/).